# How XGBoost choose where to add splits?

Tags: random-forest, cart, boosting

I have been reading about the XGBoost algorithm here:
http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model.html
and here:
https://devblogs.nvidia.com/gradient-boosting-decision-trees-xgboost-cuda/
I am still not sure how the algorithm decides where to add new splits at each iteration of boosting. I know that it builds up the forest additively, but does it consider splitting at every single possible leaf in the existing trees for the available features, as well as the possibility of adding a new tree? Or does it do something else?

Comment: Boosting (usually) builds each tree out to a pre-specified depth, so there really isn't a decision about when to stop fitting the current tree and move on to the next.  Standard boosting uses regular old regression trees, so splits are determined by searching though every possible split location for every possible predictor.  There are some optimizations to this in more advanced boosting libraries (catboost uses a clever histogram scheme to avoid searching all possible splits), but the basic algorithm is just a regular old regression tree.

Comment: @Thomas Gadd, the boosting algorithm will use the weights from the previous iteration as inputs into a weighted splitting search. There are tricks that are used in decision tree splitting to reduce the search space of split rules when the impurity functions are convex/concave.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, so am I to understand that each iteration of boosting builds a new tree and leaves those build in previous iterations alone?

Comment: XGboost doesn't pick anything.  CART picks.  XGboost gives the weights, and typically GINI or Variance tell where splitting happens.